# How do I display csv data in Highcharts?

Tags: angular, highcharts

I am trying to display the data of a csv file in my Highcharts graph.

My approach is like following:

```
export class OutputGraphComponent implements OnInit {

  title = "app";
  chart;
  updateFromInput = false;
  Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartConstructor = "chart";
  chartCallback;
  chartOptions = {
    title: {
      text: title
    },
    subtitle: {
      text: subtitle
    },
    data: {
      csv: 'assets/test.csv'
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        marker: {
          enabled: false
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

and my Imports look like this:

```
import * as Highcharts from 'highcharts';
import HC_data from 'highcharts/modules/data';
import * as HighchartsMore from "highcharts/highcharts-more";
import * as HighchartsExporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
import * as HighchartsData from "highcharts/modules/data";

//import * as data from "assets/test2.csv";

declare var require: any;
let Boost = require('highcharts/modules/boost');
let noData = require('highcharts/modules/no-data-to-display');
let More = require('highcharts/highcharts-more');
let Data = require('highcharts/modules/data');

Boost(Highcharts);
noData(Highcharts);
More(Highcharts);
HC_data(Highcharts);
Data(Highcharts);
```

However, the Graph here just displays:

> "No data to display"

Now, what I successfully tried was using this option instead:

```
csvURL: window.location.origin  + '/assets/test2.csv'
```

when using the csvUrl option, the data showed in the graph.

My problem is, for my program i need to work with the `csv:` option. 
So, what am I doing wrong and how can I get Highcharts to display csv data without it's URL correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass CSV string directly to `csv` option not a path to it:

```
...
import * as data from "../assets/test2.csv";

...
export class AppComponent {
  Highcharts = Highcharts;
  chartOptions = {
    data: {
      csv: data
    }
  };
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-tr096

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/data.csv